# What is the difference between "be done" and "get done"?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, causative-get

What is the difference between "be done" and "get done"?

For example:

- I will wash my dishes when I get done with my breakfast
- I will wash my dishes when I'm done with my breakfast.

Do these sentences have same meaning? I got done and I was done are past participle and they are same

Comment: Whether it's with ***get*** or ***be*** as the auxiliary verb, "done with breakfast" is sloppy and slangy, so best avoided. Stick to "standard English"  *I'll wash the dishes when I **have finished** my breakfast*. Or just use "when + Simple Present" to refer to the future: ***...when I finish breakfast***.

Comment: I don't see a problem with "done with breakfast".  It sounds perfectly natural to me, if a bit informal.  Maybe it's a US/UK difference.

Comment: @stangdon: Perhaps the US perspective is different. But [Top 10 British Slang Words You Must Know!](https://hs.staffordhouse.com/blog/top-10-british-slang-words-you-must-know) says ***Done with** means when you are finished with something.  “I am done with this.” This means that I am tired of this situation. You can also use this when you have had enough of someone’s attitude such as you can say “I am done with her behaviour.”* It's not *seriously* "downmarket" in BrE, but in most contexts ***done with*** is much more informal than ***finished***. Learners should probably be aware of this.

Comment: @FumbleFingers *Done with* can certainly mean "tired of" or "fed up with" in US English too (e.g. *"I'm done with this crap," he said disgustedly*), but it seems like maybe we in the US also use it to simply mean "finished" more than the British do (e.g. *"I'm done with the quarterly reports," he said with no particular judgement implied*)

Comment: @stangdon: I think in BrE we'd normally just say ***I've done** the quarterly reports* - where the ***done with*** version tends to imply at least some allusion to the "fed up with" sense. As in *Doing those reports was a tiresome chore, so I'm glad it's **over and done with** now*.

Comment: I agree with those saying 'done with' in the UK implies 'fed up with'. I might say 'I'm done with this hotel breakfast; the bacon is floppy, the sausage is tasteless and the baked beans are cold'. But I don't think it very natural, except maybe among people who watch lots of US films and TV shows.